# Form resubmission Django how to avoid for refresh or back button

Tags: jquery, html, django

I hava a django application. It is a form to fill (like answered 5 questions clicked next button and go to next five questions). All steps with questions are rendered within 1 view and 1 html file. If I click about_us or other link (to another view and html file), then back button click is followed with "Form resubmission required" and filling from the very beginning required. 
How to turn back strictly to the previous place.

View render template with the next code.

```
@secure_required
def presubmit(request):     

if request.user.is_authenticated():
    profile = request.user.profile
    try:
        profile.vodID = dictresponse['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['InitiateVOAResponse']['VOD_ID']
    except:
        profile.vodID = ''
    profile.save()
    lo = {}
        try:
        lo_user = User.objects.get(email=request.user.profile.loanOfficer)
        lo_obj = LoanManager.objects.get(user=lo_user)
        lo['isChosen'] = True
        lo['name'] = lo_obj.user.profile.firstName + ' '+lo_obj.user.profile.lastName
        lo['email'] = request.user.profile.loanOfficer
        lo['nmlsID'] = lo_obj.nmlsID
        lo['phone'] = lo_obj.phone
    except:
        lo['isChosen'] = False

    load = False
    try:
        preapp = PreApp.objects.filter(username=request.user.username).order_by('-id')[0]
        load = True
    except:
        pass
    return render_to_response('home/revisedVersion.html', {'user': request.user, 'lo':lo, 'accountcheckURL': accountcheckURL,'load':load}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
return render_to_response('home/revisedVersionSignup.html', {'user': User.objects.get(email='test9@gmail.com')}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

revisedVersionSignup has redirect back to this page if user is authenticated and did npt logged out at intermediate steps

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't have anything to do with Django, it is simply the way how browser works. You've submitted post to fill the form, then you go to other link, and then when you go back. You've asked by browser to resubmit the post, and your view doesn't know on what step to lend, so starts from 0, as you're using just one view for display forms.
You can add some kind of step counter, but I wouldn't suggest that, as it may cause problems, eventually.
So tree possible solutions

1. Change your form to be "javascript form" and you just submit results at once - if you're allowed to have scenario like this one
2. Use `_blank` in links available on form, so those links will open in new tab and won't interrupt form (easiest solution).
3. Use some warning modal to inform user that if (s)he leaves form, it need to be filled from 0.

Comment: blank and modal is what i currently use, but the customer wants it in another way )))\